# How to correctly share reactive variables setted on onMounted hook in Vue 3's composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

please read the following (wrong) code. How can I fix it?

My problem is that I'm trying to share several variables, which should be reactive, between different composables and the main app.

All those variables need DOM to be assigned, thus, they need onmounted hook. So useDropzones and usePanels both assign variables onmounted as well as the main app. And all those variables are cross-used between the cited entities. But in fact, they will be all undefined, quite obviously. How to fix?

```
const vueapp = Vue.createApp({

  setup(props, {attrs, slots, emit}){

    let validators = reactive([]);
    let panels = reactive([]);
    let code = null;

    useDropzones(code); // assigned by main app's onMounted
    usePanels(panels, validators); // it will populate panels, onmounted, used by main app below, onmounted

    onMounted(() => {
      nextTick(() => {

        code = form_elem.find('input[name="form-code"]').val(); // here I'm setting code variable, used by useDropzones()

        _.each(panels, function(panel, index){ // TODO: native?
          // execute code that populates validators, used by usePanels()
        }.bind(this));

      }); // nexttick
    }); // onmounted

    return {}
  },

});
```

Comment: This sounds like you probably should consider a store. Eg. some basic reactive store:
https://dev.to/vuesomedev/you-might-not-need-vuex-with-vue-3-52e4  or Vuex: https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: And how about Pinia? Did you ever used it? What's the difference from Vuex? https://pinia.esm.dev/

Comment: No I never used Pinia, but it seems it is also a store similar to Vuex, so I assume it would work as well. I personally prefer the simplicity of a reactive object as described in the blog over a third party store. But it depends on the complexity of your application

Answer (score 0):

Move the `useDropzones(code)` call into `onMounted()` when you've set `code` to the element reference:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    // ⛔️ moved into onMounted
    // let code = null;
    // useDropzones(code);

    onMounted(() => {
      nextTick(() => {
        const code = form_elem.find('input[name="form-code"]').val();
        useDropzones(code);
      })
    })
  }
})
```